# Time Picker dialog theme on different devices

Tags: android, android-styles, android-timepicker

I have problem with styling TimePickerDialog on different devices

I've created a style

```
<style name="MyTimePickerStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">

    <item name="android:colorAccent">@android:color/transparent</item>

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white50</item>
    <item name="android:headerTimeTextAppearance">@color/white50</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/gradient_dialog</item>
    <item name="android:headerBackground">@drawable/gradient_dialog</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/white50</item>
    <item name="android:numbersBackgroundColor">@color/dark_three</item>
    <item name="android:numbersInnerTextColor" tools:ignore="NewApi">@color/white50</item>
    <item name="android:amPmTextColor">@color/white50</item>
    <item name="android:numbersTextColor">@color/white50</item>
    <item name="android:numbersSelectorColor">@color/lilac</item>

    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyle</item>

</style>
```

and it look like this on different devices and api lvl-s
Android 26
[image]
Android 23
[image]
Android 21
[image]

I have try both creating it like

```
TimePickerDialog(this,R.style.MyTimePickerStyle, listener, hour, minute, true)
```

or adding it as style in Activity style

```
<item name="android:timePickerDialogTheme">@style/MyTimePickerStyle</item>
```

Both cases gave the same result

Creating Dialog with custom view and adding style to TimePIcker as a view inherited from `@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.TimePicker` gave different results on different devices, but it was still not the thing that is suppose to be.

Any idea how to properly style TimePicker ?

cheers
Wojtek

Comment: Will this help ? https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker

Comment: I had the same problem and couldn't fix it. So the last thing I did was to put the api check and handled both pickers differently. i.e below api 25 and above =25

Comment: :/ it is still confusing for me why some parameters works on some api and some other not. It seems like a android bug to me

Answer (score 0):

I did create a theme for my DatePicker and it worked by using attributes like that:

```
<style name="DatePickerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

try by dropping the `android:` prefix

Comment: It does work for DatePicker, but not for TimePicker :/

Answer (score 0):

Add `timepicker_drawable.xml` in drawable

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:insetLeft="16dp"
       android:insetTop="16dp"
       android:insetRight="16dp"
       android:insetBottom="16dp">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        <solid android:color="#262d37" />
    </shape>

</inset>
```

Add this is styles.xml

```
    <style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/darkBackground</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/textColor</item>
    <item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/whiteTextColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/textColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/whiteTextColor</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/timepicker_drawable</item>
</style>
```

Change colors as per your reqiurement and then  `TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(
    context, R.style.MyDialogTheme, listener,
    startHour, startMinute, is24HourFormat);`

Comment: windowBackground works, one that do not work is 'android:numbersBackgroundColor' and 'android:numbersSelectorColor'

Comment: No, but I use window background in my style, and it is applied to whole dialog